# How to prevent GNU-specific function when defined two sources

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I need to use `fcntl`'s FIFO size alteration property by using `F_SETPIPE_SZ`. To do that I need to use `#define _GNU_SOURCE`. However, my code also involves [`strerror_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r) function. Normally, I use *XSI-compliant* of it but when I add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` it automatically gives an error inherently the following since it prefers to use GNU's `strerror_r`.

```
error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
         int error_num = strerror_r(errno, ERROR_MESSAGE_BUFF, ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Due to the same reason I need to use `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE` as well for other declarations/definitions. How can I use *XSI-compliant* `strerror_r` instead when I use the following two

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
```

Comment: What do you do with `error_num` if `strerror_r()` errors out?  That likely will affect the appropriate answer.

Comment: Perhaps use `#include <linux/fcntl.h>` instead of `#define _GNU_SOURCE`. Or maybe surround all the `#include <fcntl.h>` with `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and `#undef _GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle For now just printing error message out and exits. But the case may be subject to change probably in future

Comment: Well, to preserve future flexibility, I'd think that it's probably better to isolate whichever call is the outlier from the rest of your code in it's own separate compilation unit and provide a standard-neutral wrapper.  Since you state most of your code is XSI-compliant, I'd move the GNU `fcntl()` call itself into it's own file and provide something like a `gnu_fcntl()` wrapper function.  That makes it downright obvious that the XSI-compliant code needs a GNU-specific feature.

Comment: @IanAbbott could you show the the latter usage you mention with a small code snippet please?

Comment: @AndrewHenle do you have any simpler idea if we don't consider future alterations?

Comment: My code snippet is `#define _GNU_SOURCE` `#include <fcntl.h>` `#undef _GNU_SOURCE`, but it might have unintended side effects, so I prefer Andrew Henle's suggestion of isolating the problem to a single compilation unit.

Comment: Something slightly simpler than Andrew Henle's suggestion may to have a compilation unit that defines a `const int` variable initialized to the special `F_SETPIPE_SZ` value, and declare that variable as `extern const int` in a matching header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use XSI-compliant strerror_r instead

Create a separate source file with the needed `strerror` verssion:

```
#include <string.h>
int xsi_strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen) {
   return strerror_r(errnum, buf, buflen);
}
```

Create a header file `xsi_strerror.h` with function declaration:

```
#include <stddef.h>
int xsi_strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
```

Then use in your source file that uses `fcntl` use your function:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "xsi_strerror.h"
int main() {
    if (fcntl(...)) {
        int error_num = xsi_strerror_r(errno, ERROR_MESSAGE_BUFF, ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Compile both files together.